# What grammar rules are violated by "when you" statements?

Tags: grammar, slang, when

For the past couple of years there has been a trend on twitter and facebook to post statuses with incomplete "when you" statements.  These statements are intended to imply some unstated, but obvious result.

Examples:

- When you find your fly down after you just got off stage.
- When you see your ex out with someone uglier than you.
- When you have a severe allergy and find peanuts AFTER you take a bite of your brownie.
- When your kids all have sleepovers on the same night.

These are clearly incomplete thoughts, but are they in some way grammatically incorrect?  If so, what rules do they violate?

Comment: It's an abbreviation, elision, deletion, whatever, of "*that feel[ing] when*...".

Comment: In other words, no grammar rules are violated, or even gently woken up by the scent of fresh muffins.

Answer (score 2):

> When you see your ex out with someone uglier than you.

You showed them all beginning with a capital letter and ending with a full-stop. To that extent, you could say that they violate the grammar rules for being a correct sentence.

As has been pointed out, they are all abbreviations. There are various ways of completing them, for example you could complete them as a question, e.g.

*You know that feeling you get when you see your ex out with someone uglier than you? Well that is the feeling I have right now.*

or you could complete them as a statement.

*Right now, I have the feeling you get when you see your ex out with someone uglier than you.*

**Answer**

Rather than being in  error, I think you can put them in the same category as a book title. These tend not to be complete sentences. Similarly, titles of paintings and photographs aren't usually a complete utterance.

Here are some book titles that begin with 'when'.

*When Christmas bells Ring - Katy Flynn*

*When the Professor got stuck in the snow - - Dan Rhodes*

and here are some with 'when you'

*When you reach me - Rebecca Stead*

*When you love a man who loves himself - W. Keith Campbell*

Comment: can you expand on "...violate the grammar rules for being a correct sentence."?